Ошибка с sql после перезапуска пк
2024-12-08 10:30:56 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\db' is corrupt; try to repair it
***WARNING: .\mysql\db could not be opened: Error: 126
2024-12-08 10:30:56 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: starting recovery
tables to flush: 1 0
(0.0 seconds);
2024-12-08 10:30:56 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: recovery done
2024-12-08 10:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-12-08 10:30:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

Официальная документация говорит о 4 способах восстановления:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Dump and Reload database
mysqldump db_name > dump.sql;
mysql db_name < dump.sql;


Alter Table
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = InnoDB;


Repair Table
REPAIR TABLE t1;


Forcing InnoDB Recovery
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html


Поместить в настроечный файл
    [mysqld]
    innodb_force_recovery = 1

и перезапустить сервер
